# Overriding a class to be left hand side of in operator

Tags: python, contains

Apparently the `__contains__` special method allows to implement the `in` evaulation when the object with the method is on the right hand side of it. I have a piece of code where the `in` must be implemented by the left hand operand. How do I go about it?

Comment: What types might be on the right hand side?  More detail about why this requirement has arisen would be useful.

Comment: There's no `__rcontains__`. Only the container gets to decide what it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by overriding `__eq__`.

Consider the code "value in some_list". It will iterate through some_list until it finds value. But how does it know if it found value? By comparing it. That's what you want to override.

```
class Twenty(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20
            
    def __eq__(self, y):
        print "comparing", self.x, "to", y
        return self.x == y
    
value = Twenty()
assert value in [10, 20, 30]
assert value not in [1, 2, 3]
```

output

```
comparing 20 to 10
comparing 20 to 20
comparing 20 to 1
comparing 20 to 2
comparing 20 to 3
```

Comment: The downside is that sometimes you have to implement all the comparison operators. There's some more discussion here http://gerg.ca/blog/post/2012/python-comparison/

Comment: I am not able to use this approach but I thank you for the answer.